# using threads in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

for example, I want to run two tasks ( using threads ), waiting while this tasks is end and after run next several tasks ( using threads too )
How to do this using twisted ? Any example ?

Answer (score 5):

Actually combing threads and twisted is bad idea. The whole purpose of twisted is to actually model your code in such a way that it may run concurrently (without blocking) using it's deffered mechanism.

Having said that, if you have a task which cannot escape but will always block, there is a twisted construct available called [`deferToThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html) which will execute that task in a separate thread and return the deferred to which  you can attach your call back and errorback.

The twisted documentation provides an example for that. Hope you have looked at that.

Comment: +1: try to avoid threads; Use them when there is no other option available